# Opening a MS Access database from VB that is being used by another user

Tags: database, ms-access, vb6

Is there a way to open a MS Access database from VB 6.0 that is being used by another user.

I have a service that is updating a .mdb file. I want to monitor this DB by reading some parameters from it periodically.

If I try to simply open the DB (which works if the DB is not used) like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim CurrentDBFileName
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set BaseDB = OpenDatabase("c:\temp\log_db.mdb")
    Set DestRS = BaseDB.OpenRecordset("current_log_info", dbOpenDynaset)
    DestRS.MoveFirst
    CurrentDBFileName = DestRS!CurrentDB
    BaseDB.Close
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Number; Err.Description
End Sub
```

The error I get:

3051 The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file 'b:\log_db.mdb'.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.

How can I get around this?

I can not change the service updating the MDB file since it is not mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Set BaseDB = OpenDatabase("gui_db.mdb", false)
```

To open the database in shared mode. Note that all clients must open the database in shared mode.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the best option is to convince the person who wrote the updater service that it should really open the database in shared mode, not exclusive mode.

Another option might be to split the mdb table you want to update out into a separate backend (either another Access database, or SQL Server).  Then if the service opens the frontend file exclusively, your backend file should still be shared.  The updater service shouldn't be able to see the difference.